# How to install Angular2 in MVC6 Project?

Tags: angularjs, npm, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular

I'm facing problem with ASP.NET5 MVC6 project. I have been create project that's using AngularJS to create Single Page Application. Now I want to install Angular 2 instead of AngularJS 1.

So what should I do to upgrade the project from normal AngularJS to Angular 2.

Comment: Angular is JS - you don't "install" JS

Comment: Use Nuget package manager to add angularjs package, it'll add the necessary js files to your project, you still need to make sure you're loading the js files on the html pages.

Comment: I'm stuck at the same point. I have installed Angular2 using npm. Now I want the angular2 files to appear inside the wwwroot/lib folder, the same way Bower does. I think we have to add a Gulp task to copy the files from the node_modules folder to the lib folder.

Comment: That is exactly what you have to do: create a Gulp task to copy files from node_modules to a folder in wwwroot, such as lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a basic application configured you need to include angular2 and configure system.js

Here is an example from the documentation (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
      });
      System.import('app/app');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using TypeScript with angular. I have been setup the project as I see inside the documentation and I have problem with call .ts file the browser console give me error said "app.ts is not found"
the normal path inside project it's "wwwroot/js/app.ts".

Answer (score 0):

Since the web root is wwwroot, no files or folders outside of wwwroot can be accessed. The node_modules folder is a sibling of wwwroot - both under the parent project folder.

Unfortunately, the only method is to copy the files from node_modules into wwwroot accordingly.

Be sure to update the mappings in systemjsconfig.js!